# Highlighting chosen ListView item with pre-Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-listview

A ListView is declared with `android:choiceMode="singleChoice`".

To highlight currently chosen item I declare selector as background drawable for a list item ( or listSelector for the ListView) which includes line

```
<item android:state_activated="true"   android:drawable="@color/chosen" />`
```

It works great ... with Android 3.0+, since *activated* property of View appeared not until SDK 11.

Is there a way to highlight chosen item with Android 2 ?  I expect  a simple and "natural" solution (without dirty tricks like `listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(...)` ), given that `choiceMode` feature existed from the very beginning, being completely unuseable without highlighting.

You will really make my day by providing a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

in its `**onItemClick**` listener, you could use `**TransitionDrawable**` like this. I put this code in **getView()** and highlightPosition is the item position. You could modify it according to your needs and **`reImage`** is the relative layout on the inflator xml. I have put this code in getView. You can try to put it in onItemClick..This code highlights the selected item for 2 3 seconds and then color fades from blue to white :-

```
            if(highlightPosition == position){
                viewHolderThubnail.relImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.translate);
                TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewHolderThubnail.relImage.getBackground();
                transition.startTransition(1000);
                highlightPosition =-1;
            }else{
                viewHolderThubnail.relImage.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            }
```

**translate.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_state" />
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_state" />
   </transition>
```

**new_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#92BCE7"/>
</shape>
```

**original_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand your code. I want to change the background for a particular item, not for the whole list. If I decide to avoid selector drawable, the main problem is to get the item view (which can be a ViewGroup in particular), given that getChildAt() is not 100% proof. Your code doesn't suggest a way to do that.

Comment: My code changes the background of the item selected. You could look into transition drawable

Comment: TransitionDrawable does not pick selected item automatically, while the part of code you provided does not refer to OnItemClick arguments (at least I can't see any). Can you kindly provide a more detailed code?